# How can I remove a file called "--help" with bash command line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I've somehow managed to create a file with the name "--help". If I try to remove the file using "rm" funny stuff happens. Please help

here's a printout of the dir listing:

```
[pavel@localhost test]$ ls -la
total 3640
drwxrwxr-x.  5 pavel pavel    4096 Jun 19 18:33 .
drwxrwxr-x.  6 pavel pavel    4096 Jun  9 12:23 ..
-rw-rw-r--.  1 pavel pavel 1070592 Jun 12 09:40 --help
```

Comment: Humor bonus for "please help".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Either

```
rm ./--help
```

or

```
rm -- '--help'
```

See [Utility Syntax Guideline 10 in the POSIX.1-2008 specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02) for a description of the end-of-options indicator, `--`

Comment: Prefer the first one, please.  '--' will not be understood by some commands (and even some old versions of rm !)

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
os.unlink("--help")
```

Or you can do it interactively.

Comment: you could actually do it directly from command line:

```python -c "import os; os.unlink('--help')"```

Answer (score 4):

Can you do...?:

```
ls -il
find . -inum [NUMBER] -exec rm -i {} \;
```

[Super stolen from Squeezy](https://superuser.com/a/609376/189858).

Comment: That's overkill. Just use `--` to set `end-of-options`.